# unexpected token '>' when use underscore.js template in borswer, only Chrome works good

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

A Syntax Error in IE11 is raised for my template as :

"unexpected token in safari and mobile safari"

It works well in Chrome

My template is as shown below . The data weekDays is two-dimensional array and calId is string.

```
var weekDaysTemplate = _.template(
    "<%" +
        "_.each(weekDays, week =>" +
        "{ %>" +
            "<div class='weekDays_row'>" + 
            "<% _.each(week, day =>" +
            "{" + 
                "if(day.notInMonth)" +
                "{ %>" +
                    "<div class='cal_day cal_notInMonth'></div>" +
                "<% }" +
                "else if(day.pastDay)" +
                "{ %>" +
                    "<div class='cal_day cal_disable'><%= day.day %></div>" +
                "<% }" +
                "else if(day.beyondLastDay)" +
                "{ %>" +
                    "<div class='cal_day cal_disable'><%= day.day %></div>" +
                "<% }" +
                "else" +
                "{ %>" +
                    "<div class='cal_day' id='<%= calId %>_cal_day_<%= day.utcTime %>' data-utc='<%= day.utcTime %>'><%= day.day %></div>" +
                "<% }" +
            "}); %>" +
            "</div>" + 
         "<% });" +
     "%>");
```

Comment: Does IE11 understand ES6's `=>` functions?

Comment: I happened to discover today that they don't.